# Nodejs Mongoose | findOneAndUpdate not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on node js app using express.js and mongodb with mongoose module to handle the database.

in one case I need to update a user property `languages` using `findOneAndUpdate`  method. this property is an array of objects should looks like `[{"language":"Ar","level":4}]`

when I update it using the following nodejs code :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, 
 {$set:{[req.body.key]:req.body[req.body.key]}},(err,doc)=>{

  console.log(req.body) // {id:5d1619fa7c11fa102210ef86,"languages":[{"language":"Ar","level":4}],key:"languages"}
  if (!err) {
    res.json(200,doc);
  }else{
    res.json(500,{error:err});

  }
})
```

I get the following results

[image]

but when I try same thing from the mongo shell

> db.users.findOneAndUpdate({"_id" : ObjectId("5d1619fa7c11fa102210ef86")},{ '$set': {"languages":[{"language":"Ar","level":4}]} })

I get the correct result

[image]

which is the correct expected results.

any idea why the nodejs snippet not working properly.
thanks in advance.

Comment: make sure the schema is correct

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the schema is correct.

Comment: i agree unless your body looks like `body = { key: "value", "value": "value2"}` your $set will always result as undefined with the syntax your using causing mongoose schema "protection" to kick in and voiding your chantes.

Comment: @tom I already logged the body in my code snippet above

Comment: mb didnt notice it, well the mongoosey syntax is correct and assuming the schema is too (unless you want to edit it in to double check this) the only other thing that can cause is problem is not sanitizng the body meaning level is equal to "4" and not 4. but again from the snippet this does not seem to be the case.  with all these conditions met this code works as expected on my local.

Comment: @Neil Lunn , my question not related to the returned object. it's completely different than the question you marked it as duplicated of.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting the updated result back after update has successfully run. you need to pass `new : true` in your update query as the third argument.

By default `mongodb` returns the old document after the `update`, but you can specify to return the updated document in the query.

Try this :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.id)}, 
 {$set:{[req.body.key]:req.body[req.body.key]},{new:true},(err,doc)=>{
  ...
  //doc will be updated doc here
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is not related to the returning object I know it's by default the old one, my problem is the actual data saved in my db.

Comment: can you show your mongoose schema, do you have "locations" in your schema?